# Swift View Push Notifications In App

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, push

I've got push notifications going to the application I'm working on, but I can't seem to manage them in the application. If I can't manage the notifications in the application, how else can I reduce the incrementing value of the badge icon for the application app-icon?

Comment: I think we'll need more details to help.  You can send data with the push and use that data to set the badge icon.

Comment: This question may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164339/update-badge-number-when-push-notification-is-received-when-app-is-not-open

Answer (score 1):

You can change badge count in push data, also if you need manage received push notification data, use this function:

> func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void)

Answer (score 1):

It's a snap to change the badge count from anywhere in the app:

```
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber = 4
```