# How can I update tabbar badge value on receiving notification on different index ?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, push-notification

I want to automatically update my tabbar badge value when user receive notification while he is in foreground and background in different index. I tried with following code but it doesn't work, please let me know the possibilities

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
pushDictionary = userInfo

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("PushNotification", object: self, userInfo: userInfo)

let pushNotification = PushNotification(dictionary: pushDictionary!)
notification.subtitleText = pushNotification.message

if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.Inactive {

if pushNotification.type != nil {
        if pushNotification.type == "feed" {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].badgeValue = "1"
        }
        if pushNotification.type == "message" {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![1].badgeValue = "1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: it is impossible when application stay in background . you can  send number of badgeValue from server  .

Comment: and also check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164339/update-badge-number-when-push-notification-is-received-when-app-is-not-open?rq=1